# Test if a permutation of a number exists in a collection

Tags: vb.net, combinations, basic

I'm trying to list all numbers with 3 digits where the individual digits sum to a given number.

So far I can return a list of all numbers using this Visual Basic code:

```
target = 17
i = 1
j = 1
k = 1

Do While i < 10
    Do While j < 10
        Do While k < 10
            r = i + j + k
            If r = target Then
                If i <> j And j <> k And k <> i Then
                    lsNumbers.Add(i & j & k )
                End If
            End If
            k += 1
        Loop
        If k = 10 Then k = 1
        j += 1
    Loop
    If j = 10 Then j = 1
    i += 1
Loop
```

But I want only unique, non repeating combinations.

For example for the target number 17:

179, 197, 269, 278, 287...

I want to be able to test the current number before I add it to the list, to check if it is a combination of a number already in the list - so 197 would fail because of 179, and 287 would fail because of 278

Comment: When did visual basic start using "+=" ?  I was going to remove the basic tag as this doesn't quite look like basic to me because of the increment usage, but if it is visual basic, then add that as a tag.

Comment: Not sure when it was introduced, but it definitely works. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/operators/addition-assignment-operator

Comment: I only dabbled with dot net, was not aware they added it, but it makes sense.  Thanks for clarifying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Observations

Just curious, is excluding the **0** digit on purpose?

To iterate through the possible digits, a well suited instruction pair is `FOR` `NEXT`. Definitely simpler than the `DO WHILE` that you used.

> ```
>   Loop
>   If k = 10 Then k = 1
> ```

> ```
> Loop
> If j = 10 Then j = 1
> ```

Upon loop completion, the iterator is sure to contain 10. The `IF` is redundant.

### Solution

In order to check if a number, that obeys the condition, is unique in the sense that it is not composed of the same 3 digits as an already validated number, you could consult a 3-D array. If the new number corresponds to a non-zero element in this array, it means that the new number would be using the same digits as an earlier number. That's reason to reject it.

Next code runs in QBasic. You'll have no trouble rewriting it for Visual BASIC.

```
DIM r%(1 TO 9, 1 TO 9, 1 TO 9)
FOR i% = 1 TO 9
  FOR j% = 1 TO 9
    FOR k% = 1 TO 9
      r%(i%, j%, k%) = 0
    NEXT
  NEXT
NEXT
target% = 17
FOR i% = 1 TO 9
  FOR j% = 1 TO 9
    FOR k% = 1 TO 9
      IF i% + j% + k% = target% THEN
        IF r%(i%, j%, k%) = 0 THEN
          PRINT i% * 100 + j% * 10 + k%; " ";
          r%(i%, j%, k%) = 1  ' Could do without this one because of the ascending order
          r%(i%, k%, j%) = 1
          r%(j%, i%, k%) = 1
          r%(j%, k%, i%) = 1
          r%(k%, i%, j%) = 1
          r%(k%, j%, i%) = 1
        END IF
      END IF
    NEXT
  NEXT
NEXT
```

This is my output of valid numbers:

> ```
> 179 188 269 278 359 368 377 449 458 467 557 566
> ```

Comment: Thanks for your solution!

Zero is omitted on purpose, the use case for this is to help solve something that only uses digits 1 to 9.

I just needed to add 
`If i% <> j% And j% <> k% And k% <> i% Then`
to omit answers like 188, 377, 449... because the digits can only be used once in a number.